# ggplot2 clumps all of my data points to one end of the plot, does not display other components after geom_point()

Tags: r, ggplot2

relatively new to R. I'm trying to graph a really not nice dataframe looks like this:

[image: Looks like this]

I first had the idea of making a means column and graphing that, but I thought that was not as accurate to the data I have, so I put it all in one dataframe by using decimals after years to indicate months (dat2). My first graph, where I graph the means, looks fine. This is the first graph:

[image: This is the first graph.]

However, my second graph, the one using dat2, is super messed up and I don't know why. Graph2 :
[image: Graph 2.]

The code for both graphs looks identical to me. Any help would be appreciated.
My code below for reference.

```
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(Matrix)

dat = read.csv(file = "C:\\Users\\redte\\OneDrive\\Documents\\R\\himcmdat.csv")
dat = dat %>%
    mutate(Mean = rowMeans(select(dat, c(JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC)), na.rm = TRUE))
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = YEAR, y = Mean, xmax = 2050)) + 
    geom_point(aes(y = Min, color = "red")) +
    geom_point(aes(y = Max, color = "blue")) + 
    geom_point(aes(y = Mean)) + 
    geom_point(aes(y = JAN)) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept=1075, color = "red") + 
    stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ poly(x, degree = 5, raw = TRUE), fullrange = T, level = 0)
dat2 = data.frame("Year", "Water")
for (i in 1:length(dat))
{
    for (j in 2:13)
    {
        dat2[nrow(dat2) + 1,] = c(dat[i,1] + (j-2)/12, dat[i,j])
    }
}
colnames(dat2) = c("Year", "Water")
dat2 = dat2[-c(1),]
ggplot(data = dat2, aes(x = Year, y = Water, xmax = 2050, na.rm = TRUE)) + 
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(by = 10)) + 
    geom_point(aes(y = Water)) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept=1075, color = "red") + 
    stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ poly(x, degree = 5, raw = TRUE), fullrange = T, level = 0)
```

Here is the data. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19P_XetYlQTjk_JfsmTNcRWQecWXSlCtB/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105878453678286844895&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Please provide data in the form that we reproduce the problem. You can use function `dput()`!

Comment: your water column is stored as character or factor. convert to numeric first.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your `dat2`.

First, in `for` loop, `length(dat)` is wrong. `dat` is a `data.frame`, not a `vector`. I think you intended to apply loop for each row of `dat` for `i`, then you should use `dim(dat)[1]` or `nrow(dat)` instead of `length(dat)`. Here's difference between those two.

```
> class(dat)
[1] "data.frame"
> length(dat)
[1] 13
> dim(dat)[1]
[1] 87
> nrow(dat)
[1] 87
```

So, now we change `dat2` and now it's dimension is `1045 * 2`. And now `dat2`'s
having proper values till 2022. But there's still problem that `dat2`'s components are not numeric. As you made date format as `1935.xxxx`, you need to change those values into `numeric`.

```
str(dat2)
'data.frame':   1044 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Year : chr  "1935" "1935.08333333333" "1935.16666666667" "1935.25" ...
 $ Water: chr  NA "708.7" "701.7" "752.4" ...
```

We can use `as.numeric` to make those `numeric`.

```
dat2$Year <- as.numeric(dat2$Year)
dat2$Water <- as.numeric(dat2$Water)

ggplot(data = dat2, aes(x = Year, y = Water, xmax = 2050, na.rm = TRUE)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(by = 10)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = Water)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=1075, color = "red") + 
  stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ poly(x, degree = 5, raw = TRUE), fullrange = T, level = 0)
```

[image]